# JQuery Not Working iPhone Objective-c

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have been trying to run jQuery in my UIWebView but it alerts "undefined".
[image]

Obj-C Code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)WebView {
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert($(\"[property='og:title']\").attr('content'));"];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];

}
```

However, when I run the Javascript `javascript:alert($("[property='og:title']").attr('content'));` in a safari window (http://instagram.com/lecrae/) it alerts with the correct value:

[image]

Why is this not working? and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

*Note: I am running this jQuery code and it works just fine:*

```
NSString *BGIMG = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"$(\".user-avatar\").css('background-image');"];
```

Comment: have you added jQuery to your page?

Comment: @KyleC  Yeah he's one of my favorite!